# What is the V and the Mark minecraft multiplayer UI, under the ping icon

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

[image]

Why is the V and the green mark under the ping icon, I capture this from a Youtuber.

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! Do you think you could provide more information? A link to the YouTube video, perhaps? Can you confirm the user is not running a custom interface? If custom, we could speculate, but not be able to give a definite answer to what it represents. In general interfacing terms, the V looks more like a down arrow. This could represent download speed, or simply mean network traffic is lowering. 


The green mark looks like a tick, that could mean everything is OK.

Comment: @timelord64 Believe it or not, that screenshot is actually plenty for me to be able to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a feature of Minecraft Forge. The "V" indicates a wholly vanilla server. The checkmark indicates a modded server with compatible mods. An incompatible server is indicated with a red X.